# What does 'That is' mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

“Very sorry, sir. I didn’t mean to, er...” 
The embarrassment was still reddening Jackson’s cheeks when he found the paper-knife at the bottom of the case. 
“I think I’d better keep this though, if you don’t mind, *that is*, sir.”

Answer (score 1):

> I think I’d better keep this though, if you don’t mind, that is, sir.

*That* refers to the suggestion of *keeping this*; the sentence could be rewritten as

> If you don’t mind, sir, I think I’d better keep this.

The reference to “sir” not minding comes as an afterthought after the suggestion. The person doesn't seem to be too sure of himself while speaking, and when he suggests keeping “this”, he immediately thinks of adding that his suggestion is subject to the approval of the person he's talking to. This construction is quite common:

> Maybe we should attack right away, if you approve, that is, commander.
>   This would make a perfect gift, if you agree, that is, milady.

Comment: I agree about the afterthought, but I strongly disagree that _that_ refers to the suggestion, or to anything else. As in the reference given by Andrew Lasher in his answer, _that is_ is an idiom. If you claim that _that_ refers to something, you'll need to explain what _is_ is doing.

Comment: @ColinFine I'd think _is_ is simply existential: _that suggestion is made (exists) on the premise that you don't mind_.

Answer (score 1):

At dictionary.com, that is [definition 16](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/that+is) under the idioms. The sentence you use just changes the word order a bit, but it is explaining, clarifying or giving more information.  If we simplify the word order, it would be as follows:

- I think I'd better keep this though, *that is* if you don't mind, sir.

The person is clarifying their intent to keep the knife, they will keep it only if Jackson doesn't mind.